# Django Sitemaps using incorrect timezone

Tags: django, timezone, django-sitemaps

To sum up the issue - django sitemaps seems to be using the incorrect timezone when processing dates which make up my urls.

1.) The data in the model:

```
fixture_datetime = 2016-04-03 06:15:00
```

2.) timezone in settings -

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Australia/Sydney'
```

postgres timezone has also been set to Australia/Sydney

3.) Value stored in Database:

```
"2016-04-03 06:15:00+10"
```

4.) The problem is the sitemap is retuning the URL as:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/sports/super-rugby/bulls/cheetahs/2016/04/02/
```

when it should be as follows as per the above data:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/sports/super-rugby/bulls/cheetahs/2016/04/03/
```

in the error page it is returning the date as:

```
"2016-04-03 06:15:00+00"
```

How can I get the sitemaps to use the correct timezone? Is there a setting i am forgetting?

Comment: PLS check settings.py has context_processors w/ :

               
                'django.template.context_processors.tz',

and:
USE_TZ = True

Django tz context processor (django.template.context_processors.tz)

The Django tz context processor exposes a data variable related to a project's time zone. This context processor makes the following variable accessible in Django templates:

TIME_ZONE.- Contains a project's time zone, based on the TIME_ZONE variable in the settings.py file.

Comment: "2016-04-03 06:15:00+10" is +10 hours of UTC, which makes it that datetime - 10 hours in UTC time, which is in fact 2016-04-02. There is no 'correct' timezone, just the timezone you want it in. Also thing about who is reading the sitemap - probably crawlers - not sure they care about your timezone...